# Microsoft Office batch send e-mail with attachments

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I have a .xlsx file with the columns: name, address, email. I would like to send to the whole list a plaintext mail (an identical mail for everyone) with a pdf attachment that swaps the name and the address. I would like a automatic way to do this.

Comment: If it would be suitable, you could send everyone the same plaintext email, with or without an attachment of any kind, which will pull the name, address, and email from that Excel file. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mail-merge-to-send-bulk-email-messages-0f123521-20ce-4aa8-8b62-ac211dedefa4

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to batch send e-mail with attachments, you can follow @K7AAY's suggestion to [use the Mail Merge feature in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705) [using an Excel spreadsheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3).

However, according to [KB826838](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826838/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-mail-merge-feature-in-word-2003-w), Microsoft Word doesn’t support adding attachments when doing a merge to e-mail. It also says that it can be done programmatically by using CDOSys: [KB310212](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310212).

In addition, there is an article contributed by Doug Robbins for your reference: [Mail Merge to E-mail with Attachments](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MailMerge/MergeWithAttachments.htm)

Comment: Would love to see an answer explaining how to do it programmatically!